# [Jenkins]Why User-Defined axis doesn't work with slaves

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

I created a multi-configuration project that is running a couple of automation tests. I have an user-defined axis that is running on a single node and I want to parallelize the process.

I have the following configuration:

[image: Configuration]

My problem is that both jobs will be running one the same node. 
At first it wil start "EU_Washroom" and then "EU_Linen".

[image: Jobs]

"EU_Linen" is not running on the 5th(JenkinsQFT5) node, instead is running on 4, disregarding the combination filter(`QF_SCRIPT_NAME == "EU_Linen" && slave=="Jenkins-QFT5"`).
Also at the end of the name of the job, the name of the node is added.

Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong? I'm using Jenkins version 1.598

**EDIT:** 
I deleted the combination filter and all 4 combinations were running on a single node.
Both nodes are set with the usage: "Utilize this node as much as possible"

**EDIT #2:** 
I deleted the user-defined Axis, and let only the Slave-Axis and it acts the same.
The console of the job that should ran on Jenkins-**QFT5**: `Building remotely on Jenkins-QFT4 in workspace c:\JenkinsSlave\lib\workspace\8.03.08-QF-tests\TestParalelFor8\Jenkins-QFT5`

Comment: What happens if you take the filter out? does it run 4 combinations and split the runs onto the right nodes?

Comment: It doesn't split the runs. All combinations(4) will be ran on Jenkins-QFT4.
So the problem isn't at combination filter, is in combing slave-axis with user-defined-axis.

Comment: Looking at the image above, the one without an arrow is the 'flyweight' job which manages the overall job. Try putting a shell step in with `sleep 60` to see if you can see the other one start

Comment: The nodes have Windows and they don't have Cygwin installed.
Also, I tried Windows Batch command with 
timeout(but got `ERROR: Input redirection is not supported`) and then with 
ping 127.0.0.1 -n1 -w 30000 >NULL. 
It acted all the same. All the jobs on a single node.

Comment: I deleted the user-defined Axis, and let only the Slave-Axis and it acts the same. The console of the job that should ran on Jenkins-QFT5: Building remotely on Jenkins-QFT4 in workspace c:\JenkinsSlave\lib\workspace\8.03.08-QF-tests\TestParalelFor8\Jenkins-QFT5

Comment: I tried it on my Jenkins (Mac) and it was fine - even with a user defined axis. You could try upgrading Jenkins or the plugin. Which version of the Matrix plugin do you have?

Comment: Jenkins ver. 1.617 with  
Node and Label parameter plugin v.1.5.1 
Matrix Project Plugin 1.6.

I will update the jenkins version and I will come with a response. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug in Jenkins v1.598

Answer (score 1):

In Jenkins ver. 2.5 this is working well.

Comment: It was a bug in the older version of Jenkins.